# How do I rewrite "x raised to the power y " using while-loop

Tags: python, while-loop

I could not think of any better way to raise to power, except this, but how do I refactor it? I should only use while loop, not for loop, not x**y.

```
result = 1
base = 3
counter = 1
degree = 4
while counter <= degree:
        result = base * result
        counter += 1
        print("counter %d and the result %d" %(counter, result))
print("result is ", result)
```

Comment: Probably you should post this on codereview

Comment: *Why* do you need this? What *can* you use? I.e. would `math.exp(y*math.log(x))` - or `math.pow(x,y)` be acceptable? (is this a precision problem?)

Comment: Why use a while loop when you know in advance how many times it will run? If you must use a while loop, why do you think it needs refactoring at all?

Comment: `result = base * result` can chage to `result *= base`

Answer (score 1):

#### My Favorite

```
rpow = lambda b, deg: b * rpow(b, deg - 1) if deg > 0 else 1

print("result is ", rpow(3, 4))
```

Comment: Where's the while loop the OP wants?

Comment: the while loop is implied in the recursion.  I'm making the assumption that the OP was having a bit of fun `while` asking a thoughtful question.  I responded in kind.  The question was thought provoking and can be useful for those under certain constraints.  My answer may serve to provide an alternative interesting solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `pow` function in python 2.7. It does something like

```
>>> pow(2, 3)
8
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: thx, i m only asking how to refactor this function

Comment: What do you want to refactor here? :) Your code does nothing other than looping and calculating power. Now, you don't want to give up while loop and don't want base ** exp signature as well, and you don't want alternative power method as well. So what exactly do you want?

Comment: i wanted to use while loop and use as less variables as possible - like counter, base, result etc

Comment: @ERJAN put that in the question